# DIR shows file sizes in parentheses

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, dir

On some server, I noticed that the CMD `DIR` command showed some [file sizes between parentheses](https://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/parenthesis-in-dir-command-output/200325.html). What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Remote Storage [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938469.aspx#XSLTsection131121120120):

> **Directories and Files on a Single Managed Volume**
>
> Inside each managed volume are directories and files. Placeholders are
>   shown differently from normal, untruncated files. If you are viewing
>   the file in Windows Explorer, it appears with an overlay icon. From
>   the command prompt, the Dir command displays the file size in
>   parentheses.

So I guess they are [placeholder files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/placeholder-files). These are called [OneDrive Files On-Demand](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/OneDrive-Blog/OneDrive-Files-On-Demand-For-The-Enterprise/ba-p/117234#link_9) in Windows 10.

It means that the space is not actually taken.